# how to show date created from a file in folder - Laravel

Tags: laravel, date, filesystems

I want to show all files from folder in public/folder.
I use this to show all name of the file

```
$ files = File :: allFiles ('documents');
```

How if I want to show date created or sorting data based on date created? Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You are probably looking for File Storage Mechanism.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#retrieving-files

From the docs:

> In addition to reading and writing files, Laravel can also provide
>   information about the files themselves.

Example:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

$time = Storage::lastModified('file.jpg');
```

The lastModified method returns the UNIX timestamp of the last time the file was modified:

> If you would like to retrieve a list of all files within a given
>   directory including all sub-directories, you may use the  allFiles
>   method:

Example:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

$files = Storage::allFiles($directory);
```

Comment: oh i've tried and its only show date from  a file. 
i want to show all my files in storage  in table, with filename and date modified. any advice?

Comment: To retrieve all files in a directory use this code '$files = Storage::allFiles($directory);'. Updated the answer

Comment: What you show is time file was modified, not created. I couldn't find in storage class a way to retrieve created time, anyway it is good to have it in mind.